# Как из ссылки на картинку (в String) сделать Drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Добрый день.

Есть путь к картинке, который записан в String. Картинка хранится где-то в интернете.

Нужно сделать Drawable, который будет содержать эту картинку, чтобы потом ее можно было закинуть в ImageView.

Можно ли такое сделать?

Comment: А не проще ли держать всё-таки строку, и как будет необходимость, то загрузить картинку в imageview? В чем необходимость drawable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна одна из библиотек для загрузки-кэширования-отображения картинок из сети. Например [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) или [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

В первом случае код будет такой:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Во втором так:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Писать свой велосипед не стоит. Тем более, что у UIL есть слушатеь загрузки, в коий приходит Bitmap, коий просто превратить в Drawable, если ам это действительно надо. Хотя, скорее всего, вам это и не надо.

Comment: У меня тут RecyclerView, который содержит сетку из ImageView. Не подскажите, где именно стоит использовать Picasso, в частности, код который вы привели выше? В onBindViewHolder адаптера, либо же во ViewHolder'е?

Comment: @Crok, на этот счёт есть разные мнения. Лично мне больше нравится в onBindViewHolder. И UIL вместо Picasso. Но конкретно сказать в чём разница я вам не смогу. Работать будет в любых комбинациях.